# Starting point of Schwarz-Christoffel integral

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, contour-integration

In the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping, we write the integral as

$$F(z) = \int_{z_0}^z (s-x_1)^{-k_1}\dotsb(s-x_n)^{-k_n} ds$$

How do we choose $z_0$ in this case?

On the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping), it writes the integral as

$$F(\zeta) = \int^\zeta \left( \frac{K}{(w-a)^{1-\alpha/\pi}(w-b)^{1-\beta/\pi}\dotsb} \right),$$

omitting reference to $z_0$ altogether. What can this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of the Schwarz-Christoffel formula focuses on $F'$, especially its argument. Once we figure out what $F'$ is, the map $F$ is determined up to the infamous additive constant $+C$. The additive constant can be found, alongside other constants involved in the  formula ($K$, $x_1,\dots,x_n$) from the requirement that $F(x_j)$ is the $j$th vertex of the polygon. The example given in the linked Wikipedia article illustrates this process.

The notation with $\int_{z_0}^z$ may be convenient when the polygon contains $0$ (possibly on the boundary), because we will choose $z_0$  to be the point that should be mapped to $0$. However, if the target polygon stays away from $0$, writing the map as $\int_{z_0}^z$ is incorrect.

Comment: Why does writing $\int_{z_0}^z$ imply that $0$ will end up inside the polygon? Wouldn't it be outside the polygon if $\Im{(z_0)}<0$? (I'm still figuring out how this works)

Comment: @EricAuld You could try placing $z_0$ in the lower halfplane to create the needed additive constant, but you'll have to face some issues then: (i) how do you define the product $(s-x_j)^{-k_j}$ in the lower half plane, which branch to take of which factor? (ii) along which path do you integrate now? Since there may be branch points or poles at $x_j$, it matters on which side of such a point the path passes... Our product formula for $F'$ is meant for the upper halfplane, and interpreting it in the lower half-plane (i.e., outside of the domain that is mapped to the polygon) is not a good idea.